# Parse Issues in the AFNetworking File

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I uploaded AFNetworking and UIKIT+AFNetworking files into my Project and wrote a code. Code I wrote hasn't got any problem but there are 20 errors coming from AFNetworking. All the errors are because of the parse issues. I took the files from [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Does anyone knows how to fix that?

Here is the error list:

```
CompileC /Users/user30357/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DovizAltin-ggicxzzzxoadfobgfihaiyfekgib/Build/Intermediates/DovizAltin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DovizAltin.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.o DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin"
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/user30357"
    /Applications/Xcode6.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/user30357/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -iquote /Users/user30357/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DovizAltin-ggicxzzzxoadfobgfihaiyfekgib/Build/Intermediates/DovizAltin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DovizAltin.build/DovizAltin-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/user30357/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DovizAltin-ggicxzzzxoadfobgfihaiyfekgib/Build/Intermediates/DovizAltin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DovizAltin.build/DovizAltin-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/user30357/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DovizAltin-ggicxzzzxoadfobgfihaiyfekgib/Build/Intermediates/DovizAltin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DovizAltin.build/DovizAltin-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/user30357/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DovizAltin-ggicxzzzxoadfobgfihaiyfekgib/Build/Intermediates/DovizAltin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DovizAltin.build/DovizAltin-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/user30357/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DovizAltin-ggicxzzzxoadfobgfihaiyfekgib/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode6.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/user30357/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DovizAltin-ggicxzzzxoadfobgfihaiyfekgib/Build/Intermediates/DovizAltin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DovizAltin.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/user30357/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DovizAltin-ggicxzzzxoadfobgfihaiyfekgib/Build/Intermediates/DovizAltin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DovizAltin.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/user30357/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DovizAltin-ggicxzzzxoadfobgfihaiyfekgib/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/user30357/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DovizAltin-ggicxzzzxoadfobgfihaiyfekgib/Build/Intermediates/DovizAltin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DovizAltin.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/user30357/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DovizAltin-ggicxzzzxoadfobgfihaiyfekgib/Build/Intermediates/DovizAltin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DovizAltin.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.dia -c /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.m -o /Users/user30357/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DovizAltin-ggicxzzzxoadfobgfihaiyfekgib/Build/Intermediates/DovizAltin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DovizAltin.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.o

In file included from /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.m:24:
In file included from /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h:32:
In file included from /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperation.h:23:
In file included from /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h:25:
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:27:1: error: unknown type name 'NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN'
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:34:1: error: cannot combine with previous '(error)' declaration specifier
@protocol AFURLRequestSerialization <NSObject, NSSecureCoding, NSCopying>
^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:45:4: error: expected a type
- (nullable NSURLRequest *)requestBySerializingRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
   ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:46:48: error: expected a type
                               withParameters:(nullable id)parameters
                                               ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:47:58: error: expected ')'
                                        error:(NSError * __nullable __autoreleasing *)error;
                                                         ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:47:47: note: to match this '('
                                        error:(NSError * __nullable __autoreleasing *)error;
                                              ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:141:19: error: expected a type
- (void)setValue:(nullable NSString *)value
                  ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:151:4: error: expected a type
- (nullable NSString *)valueForHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field;
   ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:196:47: error: expected a type
- (void)setQueryStringSerializationWithBlock:(nullable NSString * (^)(NSURLRequest *request, id parameters, NSError * __autoreleasing *error))block;
                                              ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:223:45: error: expected a type
                                parameters:(nullable id)parameters
                                            ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:224:55: error: expected ')'
                                     error:(NSError * __nullable __autoreleasing *)error;
                                                      ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:224:44: note: to match this '('
                                     error:(NSError * __nullable __autoreleasing *)error;
                                           ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:249:58: error: expected a type
                                             parameters:(nullable NSDictionary *)parameters
                                                         ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:250:58: error: expected a type
                              constructingBodyWithBlock:(nullable void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData))block
                                                         ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:251:68: error: expected ')'
                                                  error:(NSError * __nullable __autoreleasing *)error;
                                                                   ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:251:57: note: to match this '('
                                                  error:(NSError * __nullable __autoreleasing *)error;
                                                        ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:266:59: error: expected a type
                                       completionHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSError *error))handler;
                                                          ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:290:42: error: expected ')'
                        error:(NSError * __nullable __autoreleasing *)error;
                                         ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:290:31: note: to match this '('
                        error:(NSError * __nullable __autoreleasing *)error;
                              ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:307:42: error: expected ')'
                        error:(NSError * __nullable __autoreleasing *)error;
                                         ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:307:31: note: to match this '('
                        error:(NSError * __nullable __autoreleasing *)error;
                              ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:318:36: error: expected a type
- (void)appendPartWithInputStream:(nullable NSInputStream *)inputStream
                                   ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:354:32: error: expected a type
- (void)appendPartWithHeaders:(nullable NSDictionary *)headers
                               ^
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user30357/Desktop/DovizAltin/DovizAltin/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h:471:1: error: unknown type name 'NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END'
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Comment: can you please show that error list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to downloading the most recent version.

For whose that will encounter with the same problem, IOS8 has some issues with the versions with earlier of AFNetworking 2.4 . Consider downloading 2.4+ versions or at least 2.4.